# Echoing users by group name in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

What I want to do is click a name of a group(every group what I create other than poweruser and admin groups) and that will echo all of the users in that group from the database. I have figured out the code so far but now my problem is how will I print it all out when clicking the name of the group?

My code so far is:

```
<h3>Groups</h3>
<?php
include('db.php');
if (isset($_GET["groupID"])) {
$sql="SELECT `group`.*, `user`.* FROM `user` inner join `group` on group.groupID=user.groupID where group.groupID= " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["groupID"]) ;
} else {
$sql="SELECT * FROM `group` WHERE groupName <> 'admin' AND groupName <> 'poweruser'"  ;
}
$result=mysql_query($sql,$connection);
while($line=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<a href='index.php?page=groups&group=".$line['groupID']."'>".$line['groupName'].'</a><br />';
}
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: So you want to load the list dynamically, i.e. without loading a new page? If yes, Ajax is your friend.

Comment: Your call to `mysql_real_escape_string` does not protect you from anything, since you are not enclosing the resulting string in quotation marks. This is exactly the reason one should use [parametrized queries](http://php.net/prepared_statements)

Answer (score 1):

On top of the $_GET["group"] issue, it doesn't look like you're printing out the users anywhere.

You should move the output into the if block, and create new output for the first condition.

```
<?php
include('db.php');
if (isset($_GET["groupID"])) {
$sql="SELECT `group`.*, `user`.* FROM `user` inner join `group` on group.groupID=user.groupID where group.groupID= " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["groupID"]) ;

$result=mysql_query($sql,$connection);

//Output users after Group Selected
//Could be placed outside the if block to allow user to select a different group
echo("<h3>Users</h3>");
while($line=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    //echo out the user data here
}

} else {
$sql="SELECT * FROM `group` WHERE groupName <> 'admin' AND groupName <> 'poweruser'"  ;
$result=mysql_query($sql,$connection);

//Output to let user select group.
echo("<h3>Groups</h3>");
while($line=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<a href='index.php?page=groups&group=".$line['groupID']."'>".$line['groupName'].'</a><br />';
}

}
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is still not echoing the users by group even when I added what you wrote above. I get all the groups showing normally but when I click the group name, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I just edited an error in the code I originally posted.  There was some odd spacing in the anchor tag.  If you're getting nothing after clicking, it's possible that the mysql_query is throwing an error and PHP isn't set to report them.

Comment: With this code I am not receiving any errors but when clicking a group nothing is happening(previously I wrote it's linking to index.php but that was because I had mistake). The address is: "localhost/nameofmypage/index.php?page=groups&group=4". Address on the groups page is: "localhost/nameofmypage/index.php?page=groups" What can I do about it? On the index.php I am including my groups page as: "if($page=='groups') include('groups.php');" as I have done with all my other pages also.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_GET["groupID"])) {
```

should that not be

```
if (isset($_GET["group"])) {
```

also change the $_GET["groupID"] to $_GET["group"] in ur $sql query

Comment: This doesn't answer the question BobSapp asked

Comment: yes i know that, thats why i upvoted chris's answer. i made a newbie mistake and failed to spot the obvious lol

Answer (score 0):

The following code is an example on how you could it. Just put it below the code you already have:

```
if ($_GET['page'] == 'groups'):
$groupID = $_GET['groupID'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE groupID = '$groupID'"; 
$res = mysql_query($sql); //MySQL query
$count = mysql_num_rows($res); //This counts our results
if($count != 0): //This makes sure we have at least 1 result
   while($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)):
     echo $user['name'];
   endwhile;
endif;
endif;
```

Comment: This is assuming that the code in the OP is in a file called index.php. In that case I would wrap this code in an if ($_GET['page'] == 'groups') { ... } statement.

Comment: It's in a separate file called groups.php

Comment: So it inside the while loop you will have include 'pathtofile/group.php'; Is it working okay for you?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am still not getting this one to work either. The group names are showing but nothing happens from clicking them. Any idea what to do?

Comment: Are you running a MySQL query to find the users? Have you got PHP errors switched on? Also in my code above try change line 4 to this $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: With PHP errors on I got this: "Notice: Undefined index: page in C:\xampp\htdocs\NameOfMyPage\groups.php on line 25" Line 25 is "if ($_GET['page'] == 'groups'):" What can I do about this?

Comment: Change it to if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'groups'). That will fix that. Still no results when you click on a group?

Comment: I just noticed in your initial message "if ($_GET['page'] == 'groups'):" ends in ":" instead of ";". With the fix or with "if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'groups');" I am getting an error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDIF in C:\xampp\htdocs\NameOfMyPage\groups.php on line 35" and nothing is showing now on the page anymore. Line 35 is the second: "endif;".

Comment: That is one way of coding. You have "if(condition): <code here> endif;" instead of "if(condition) { <code here> }". I am afraid this is turning into a discussion which is against the site rules. You can email me peter_s_93@live.com if you wish more help :)

Answer (score 0):

Add Peter Stuart's code in your file and change 
`<a href='index.php?page ... >`  to  `<a href='groups.php?page ... >`